# How create column that lists number of occurrences of X in another column?

Tags: r

I've got a huge df that include the following:

```
subsetdf <- data_frame(Id=c(1:6),TicketNo=c(15,16,15,17,17,17))
```

I want to add a column, `GroupSize`, that tells for each `Id` how many other `Id`s share the same `TicketNo` value. In other words, I want output like this:

```
TheDream <- data_frame(Id=c(1:6),TicketNo=c(15,16,15,17,17,17),GroupSize=c(2,1,2,3,3,3)
```

I've unsuccessfully tried:

```
subsetdf <- subsetdf %>%
  group_by(TicketNo) %>%
  add_count(name = "GroupSize")
```

I'd like to use `mutate()` but I can't seem to get it right.

**Edit**
With the `GroupSize` column now added, I want to add a final column that looks at the values in two other columns and returns the value of whichever is higher. So I've got:

```
df <- data_frame(Id=c(1:6),TicketNo=c(15,16,15,17,17,17),GroupSize=c(2,1,2,3,3,3),FamilySize=c(2,2,1,1,4,4)
```

And I want:

```
df <- data_frame(Id=c(1:6),TicketNo=c(15,16,15,17,17,17),GroupSize=c(2,1,2,3,3,3),FamilySize=c(2,2,1,1,4,4),FinalSize=c(2,2,2,3,4,4)
```

I've unsuccessfully tried:

```
df <- df %>% pmax(df$GroupSize, df$FamilySize) %>% dplyr::mutate(FinalSize = n())
```

That attempt earns me the error: `Error: ! Subscript` i`is a matrix, the data`value` must have size 1.
Backtrace:

1. ... %>% dplyr::mutate(Groupsize = n())
2. base::pmax(., train_data$Family_size, train_data$PartySize)
3. tibble:::`[<-.tbl_df`(`*tmp*`, change, value = `<int>`)
4. tibble:::tbl_subassign_matrix(x, j, value, j_arg, substitute(value))`

Comment: You need `n()` i.e. `subsetdf %>% group_by(TicketNo) %>% mutate(GroupSize = n())`

Comment: Unfortunately, @akrun, this returns an error: Error in `n()`:
! Must be used inside dplyr verbs.

Comment: `mutate` is from `dplyr`.  Probably, you loaded plyr as well, try `dplyr::mutate(GroupSize = n())`

Comment: Ah, yes--you're correct. Thank you, @akrun. This isn't the first time you've helped me, and I am once again grateful. Actually, if I edit the question would you be willing to answer a followup? (Also, if you'll make your answer an "answer" I'd be happy to give you the green check mark).

Comment: You can use `pmax` within `mutate` .e. `df %>% dplyr::mutate(FinalSize = pmax(GroupSize, FamilySize))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to use `mutate` use `n()` to get the group size.  Also, make sure that the `mutate` is from `dplyr` (as there is also a `plyr::mutate` which could mask the function if it is loaded later)

```
library(dplyr)
subsetdf %>%
   group_by(TicketNo) %>%
   dplyr::mutate(GroupSize = n())
```